# How to save a list in a function using recursion

Tags: python, nested-lists

I have written a function which flattens lists with nested lists, but I'm having some problems with how to save the elements in a list within the function. Let me demonstrate what the problems is, here is the function:

```
new_list = []

def flatten_list(old_list):
    for i in old_list:
        if isinstance(i,list):
            flatten_list(i)
        else:
            new_list.append(i)
    return new_list
```

Input:

```
flatten_list(['a', 1, ['b', ['c'], 2], 'd', 3])
```

Output:

```
['a', 1, 'b', 'c', 2, 'd', 3]
```

It does what it's suppose to do, which is to flatten the given list. However, I want the "new_list" to be inside the function. How can I change the function so that I can keep the "new_list" inside the function instead of having it outside of it? Also I would prefer NOT to have the "new_list" as a parameter in the function, that is I would rather it be a variable.

Any ideas or suggestions are greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: you put `new_list = []` into the function?

Comment: Why don't you define inside the function. Shouldn't throw error because you will return it anyway.

Comment: Recursion is almost always an inefficient way to solve a problem, and should only be used as a last resort.

Comment: It won't register if the element is a list because of the recursion, so it will just skip it. @KlausD.

Comment: You are ignoring the return values of `flatten_list()` within your implementation. Recursive function calls are exactly the same thing as calls to other functions; if you want to use the result they produce, then you do need to use that result. Once you do that, then putting `new_list` inside the function is trivial. Just extend `new_list` with the returned value: `new_list.extend(flatten_list(i))` or `new_list += flatten_list(i)`.

Comment: @BlueSheepToken: you should definitely **not** put `new_list` as an argument. There is absolutely no need to do that here, and using mutable defaults in functions leads to [suprises for those that expect the default to be recreated each call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument).

Comment: Thank you! This was what I was looking for. @MartijnPieters